# N variable Kmap in C#

Tags: c#, boolean-expression

I am working on project which will take Boolean Expression as an input and Minimize it using Kmap. So far i am able to Get min terms from the Expression. Now i am stucked on how to get Minimize expression using min terms for any no of variable in kmap.

Comment: What does your input look like?  Is it a string, is it an `Expression`, have you parsed it into some other custom objects of yours?  Are you generally familiar with how to minimize an expression using k-maps by hand?

Comment: My Input is a string(Boolean Expression) i am able to parse it and generate truth table. And from the truth table i have min terms which is an array of Integers.

Comment: Ya i know it by hand..But its difficult to implement programatically.

Comment: That's because the solution was *designed* to be easy for people.  There are other methods of simplifying expressions designed to be easier for computers.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. It will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Hey thanks Guys ... i find the method myself. I can Achieved by quine mccluskey method.